# Extract information according to requirement from a file which contains fields separated by as pecial Character

Tags: shell, awk, extract

Please, I have a log file "log1.txt" that contains fields separated by the character "|" I want to retrieve rows according to specific requirements
and I have another configuration file "code.conf" or I put the values ​​found in the field 5.
here is the log file:

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
abc|2|  11|   3| 1000|   0|scql|  29|   |   |   0|   0| plk| stv| 2| 0

trc|2|  20|   3| 1200|   0|tkgl|   0| pajd|jahd| 0| 0| klm|fdkl|1|0

klm|2|  0|   3| 1300|   0|mlpo|  0|   |   |   0|   0| qnhd| pkjs| 2| 0

klm|2|  0|   3| 1600|   0|mlpo|  22|   |   |   0|   0| qnhd| pkjs| 2| 0
```

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

And here is the configuration file "code.conf"

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
1000

1300

1200
```

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Now I want to retrieve from the log file just lines corresponding to this conditions:

field 2 equal to "2"

field 3 equal to "0" or "20"

field 4 equal to "3"

field 8 equal to "0"

field 5 must contain one of the values ​​declared in the configuration file.

here's what I tried to do:

```
#!/bin/sh

cat /home/code.conf | awk '{ print "if (substr($2,1,1)==\""2"\" && substr($3,1,1)==\""0"\" || substr($3,1,2)==\""20"\" && substr($4,1,1)==\""3"\" && substr($8,1,1)==\""0"\" && substr($5,1,"length($5)")==\""$1"\" ) { print $0};"}'> /home/awk-code.awk

sed -i '1i{'  /home/awk-code.awk

echo "}" >> /home/awk-code.awk

awk -f /home/awk-code.awk /home/log1.txt > /home/log2.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An awk command can handle all of this in one command:

```
awk -F' *\\| *' 'FNR==NR {a[$1];next}
         $2==2 && ($3==0 || $3==20) && $4==3 && $5 in a && $8==0' code.conf file
trc|2|  20|   3| 1200|   0|tkgl|   0| pajd|jahd| 0| 0| klm|fdkl|1|0
klm|2|  0|   3| 1300|   0|mlpo|  0|   |   |   0|   0| qnhd| pkjs| 2| 0
```

Comment: please and if I want to count and sort based on field 5?

Comment: Pipe with `sort -t '|' -k5,5` but it is better to ask a new question